# How to get the input from the Tkinter Text Widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

How to get Tkinter input from the `Text` widget?

**EDIT**

I asked this question to help others with the same problem - *that* is the reason why there is no example code. This issue had been troubling me for hours and I used this question to teach others. *Please* do not rate it as if it was a real question - the answer is the thing that matters.

Answer (score 215, accepted):

To get Tkinter input from the text box, you must add a few more attributes to the normal `.get()` function. If we have a text box `myText_Box`, then this is the method for retrieving its input.

```
def retrieve_input():
    input = self.myText_Box.get("1.0",END)
```

The first part, `"1.0"` means that the input should be read from line one, character zero (ie: the very first character). `END` is an imported constant which is set to the string `"end"`. The `END` part means to read until the end of the text box is reached. The only issue with this is that it actually adds a newline to our input. So, in order to fix it we should change `END` to `end-1c`(Thanks [Bryan Oakley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley)) The `-1c` deletes 1 character, while `-2c` would mean delete two characters, and so on.

```
def retrieve_input():
    input = self.myText_Box.get("1.0",'end-1c')
```

Comment: You should do `"end-1c"` or `END+"1c"`, otherwise you'll get the extra newline that the text widget always adds.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley Thanks, so does `-1c/1c`mean "delete a newline?" Also, can it be used in areas other than the text widget/Tkinter?

Comment: Check out the Text widget section of the [NMTech reference](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html) → [Text widget indices](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text-index.html)

Comment: `'1.0'` is line 1 column 0, i.e. the first character. I agree with Bryan, use `'end-1c'`. It's OK to edit and improve the answer based on suggestions made in comments.

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks. Out of curiosity, If I were to do `END -2c` would that delete 2 characters?

Comment: @HonestAbe so... `0.1` would get everything from the second column onwards (assuming I used END afterwards.) Also, are we allowed to use lowercase letters in `END`, I had always assumed that capitals were necessary.

Comment: See [this](http://pastie.org/6159791). `END` is an imported name that is equivalent to the string `'end'`. Thus you can use the string `'end'` directly.

Comment: This is what you want: `.get('1.0', 'end-1c')`

Comment: Thanks! Just out of curiosity, if I were to write `end+1c` would that add a new line to the code? Lastly, Bryan and Honest Abe, thank you guys so much for helping me out with my simple Tkinter and Python questions. You have really helped me to gain a deeper understanding of the language, and have always been courteous, prompt, and best of all - knowlegable. I am sure that your advice will help me as I move to highschool and beyond!

Comment: The example you added doesn't work. The quotes around `'end-1c'` are necessary for it to be a single string. `'end'` is an alias for the index after the last character. So if `'end'` was `'3.8'` then `'end-1c'` would be `'3.7'`. I want to again recommend reviewing: [Text widget indices](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text-index.html).

Comment: @xxmbabanexx: no, "end+1c" won't add a newline.

Comment: this does not work for me, I get `TclError: bad text index "END-1c"`

Comment: @BryanOakley it should be `END+"-1c"` instead of `END+"1c"`

Comment: @WoJ: I know; I was answering the question asked earlier about whether "end+1c" would add a newline. See the comment by xxmbabanexx.

Comment: @BrianOakley: I was referring to your first comment (at 2:12) where there is just a typo (the missing minus sign).  I actually learned from this comment how to get rid of the \n :)

Comment: I tried to use this with `text = Tkinter.Text(root, width=100, height=50)`, but when I did `file_input = text.get("1.0", "end-1c")`, I got the error `TclError: invalid command name ".3038449376L"` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your text widget is probably empty, so you can't subtract one character, i.e. the presented code is flawed. I suggest just getting all the text by just using "end". Then feel free to remove any trailing newline if you wish after checking for it. Personally, I prefer multi-line text to always have a trailing newline. That's why they did it that way.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who contributed to this answer. This was the only good explanation I could find about why 1.0 and end-1c was used. This concisely cleared up the confusion.

Answer (score 32):

Here is how I did it with python 3.5.2:

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
def retrieve_input():
    inputValue=textBox.get("1.0","end-1c")
    print(inputValue)

textBox=Text(root, height=2, width=10)
textBox.pack()
buttonCommit=Button(root, height=1, width=10, text="Commit", 
                    command=lambda: retrieve_input())
#command=lambda: retrieve_input() >>> just means do this when i press the button
buttonCommit.pack()

mainloop()
```

with that, when i typed "blah blah" in the text widget and pressed the button, whatever i typed got printed out. So i think that is the answer for storing user input from Text widget to variable.

Answer (score 9):

To get Tkinter input from the text box in python 3 the complete student level program used by me is as under:

```
#Imports all (*) classes,
#atributes, and methods of tkinter into the
#current workspace

from tkinter import *

#***********************************
#Creates an instance of the class tkinter.Tk.
#This creates what is called the "root" window. By conventon,
#the root window in Tkinter is usually called "root",
#but you are free to call it by any other name.

root = Tk()
root.title('how to get text from textbox')


#**********************************
mystring = StringVar()

####define the function that the signup button will do
def getvalue():
##    print(mystring.get())
#*************************************

Label(root, text="Text to get").grid(row=0, sticky=W)  #label
Entry(root, textvariable = mystring).grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=E) #entry textbox

WSignUp = Button(root, text="print text", command=getvalue).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W) #button


############################################
# executes the mainloop (that is, the event loop) method of the root
# object. The mainloop method is what keeps the root window visible.
# If you remove the line, the window created will disappear
# immediately as the script stops running. This will happen so fast
# that you will not even see the window appearing on your screen.
# Keeping the mainloop running also lets you keep the
# program running until you press the close buton
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The OP's question was about the `Text` widget.

Answer (score 8):

In order to obtain the string in a `Text` widget one can simply use [`get`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.get-method) method defined for `Text` which accepts 1 to 2 arguments as `start` and `end` positions of characters, `text_widget_object.get(start, end=None)`. If only `start` is passed and `end` isn't passed it returns only the single character positioned at `start`, if `end` *is* passed as well, it returns all characters in between positions `start` and `end` as  string.

There are also special strings, that are *variables* to the underlying Tk. One of them would be `"end"` or `tk.END` which represents the variable position of the very last char in the `Text` widget. An example would be to returning all text in the widget, with `text_widget_object.get('1.0', 'end')` or `text_widget_object.get('1.0', 'end-1c')` if you don't want the last newline character.

## Demo

See below demonstration that *selects* the characters in between the given positions with sliders:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except:
    import Tkinter as tk


class Demo(tk.LabelFrame):
    """
    A LabeFrame that in order to demonstrate the string returned by the
    get method of Text widget, selects the characters in between the
    given arguments that are set with Scales.
    """

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.LabelFrame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.start_arg = ''
        self.end_arg = None
        self.position_frames = dict()
        self._create_widgets()
        self._layout()
        self.update()


    def _create_widgets(self):
        self._is_two_args = tk.Checkbutton(self,
                                    text="Use 2 positional arguments...")
        self.position_frames['start'] = PositionFrame(self,
                                    text="start='{}.{}'.format(line, column)")
        self.position_frames['end'] = PositionFrame(   self,
                                    text="end='{}.{}'.format(line, column)")
        self.text = TextWithStats(self, wrap='none')
        self._widget_configs()


    def _widget_configs(self):
        self.text.update_callback = self.update
        self._is_two_args.var = tk.BooleanVar(self, value=False)
        self._is_two_args.config(variable=self._is_two_args.var,
                                    onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
        self._is_two_args['command'] = self._is_two_args_handle
        for _key in self.position_frames:
            self.position_frames[_key].line.slider['command'] = self.update
            self.position_frames[_key].column.slider['command'] = self.update


    def _layout(self):
        self._is_two_args.grid(sticky='nsw', row=0, column=1)
        self.position_frames['start'].grid(sticky='nsew', row=1, column=0)
        #self.position_frames['end'].grid(sticky='nsew', row=1, column=1)
        self.text.grid(sticky='nsew', row=2, column=0,
                                                    rowspan=2, columnspan=2)
        _grid_size = self.grid_size()
        for _col in range(_grid_size[0]):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(_col, weight=1)
        for _row in range(_grid_size[1] - 1):
            self.grid_rowconfigure(_row + 1, weight=1)


    def _is_two_args_handle(self):
        self.update_arguments()
        if self._is_two_args.var.get():
            self.position_frames['end'].grid(sticky='nsew', row=1, column=1)
        else:
            self.position_frames['end'].grid_remove()


    def update(self, event=None):
        """
        Updates slider limits, argument values, labels representing the
        get method call.
        """

        self.update_sliders()
        self.update_arguments()


    def update_sliders(self):
        """
        Updates slider limits based on what's written in the text and
        which line is selected.
        """

        self._update_line_sliders()
        self._update_column_sliders()


    def _update_line_sliders(self):
        if self.text.lines_length:
            for _key in self.position_frames:
                self.position_frames[_key].line.slider['state'] = 'normal'
                self.position_frames[_key].line.slider['from_'] = 1
                _no_of_lines = self.text.line_count
                self.position_frames[_key].line.slider['to'] = _no_of_lines
        else:
            for _key in self.position_frames:
                self.position_frames[_key].line.slider['state'] = 'disabled'


    def _update_column_sliders(self):
        if self.text.lines_length:
            for _key in self.position_frames:
                self.position_frames[_key].column.slider['state'] = 'normal'
                self.position_frames[_key].column.slider['from_'] = 0
                _line_no = int(self.position_frames[_key].line.slider.get())-1
                _max_line_len = self.text.lines_length[_line_no]
                self.position_frames[_key].column.slider['to'] = _max_line_len
        else:
            for _key in self.position_frames:
                self.position_frames[_key].column.slider['state'] = 'disabled'


    def update_arguments(self):
        """
        Updates the values representing the arguments passed to the get
        method, based on whether or not the 2nd positional argument is
        active and the slider positions.
        """

        _start_line_no = self.position_frames['start'].line.slider.get()
        _start_col_no = self.position_frames['start'].column.slider.get()
        self.start_arg = "{}.{}".format(_start_line_no, _start_col_no)
        if self._is_two_args.var.get():
            _end_line_no = self.position_frames['end'].line.slider.get()
            _end_col_no = self.position_frames['end'].column.slider.get()
            self.end_arg = "{}.{}".format(_end_line_no, _end_col_no)
        else:
            self.end_arg = None
        self._update_method_labels()
        self._select()


    def _update_method_labels(self):
        if self.end_arg:
            for _key in self.position_frames:
                _string = "text.get('{}', '{}')".format(
                                                self.start_arg, self.end_arg)
                self.position_frames[_key].label['text'] = _string
        else:
            _string = "text.get('{}')".format(self.start_arg)
            self.position_frames['start'].label['text'] = _string


    def _select(self):
        self.text.focus_set()
        self.text.tag_remove('sel', '1.0', 'end')
        self.text.tag_add('sel', self.start_arg, self.end_arg)
        if self.end_arg:
            self.text.mark_set('insert', self.end_arg)
        else:
            self.text.mark_set('insert', self.start_arg)


class TextWithStats(tk.Text):
    """
    Text widget that stores stats of its content:
    self.line_count:        the total number of lines
    self.lines_length:      the total number of characters per line
    self.update_callback:   can be set as the reference to the callback
                            to be called with each update
    """

    def __init__(self, master, update_callback=None, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self._events = ('<KeyPress>',
                        '<KeyRelease>',
                        '<ButtonRelease-1>',
                        '<ButtonRelease-2>',
                        '<ButtonRelease-3>',
                        '<Delete>',
                        '<<Cut>>',
                        '<<Paste>>',
                        '<<Undo>>',
                        '<<Redo>>')
        self.line_count = None
        self.lines_length = list()
        self.update_callback = update_callback
        self.update_stats()
        self.bind_events_on_widget_to_callback( self._events,
                                                self,
                                                self.update_stats)


    @staticmethod
    def bind_events_on_widget_to_callback(events, widget, callback):
        """
        Bind events on widget to callback.
        """

        for _event in events:
            widget.bind(_event, callback)


    def update_stats(self, event=None):
        """
        Update self.line_count, self.lines_length stats and call
        self.update_callback.
        """

        _string = self.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
        _string_lines = _string.splitlines()
        self.line_count = len(_string_lines)
        del self.lines_length[:]
        for _line in _string_lines:
            self.lines_length.append(len(_line))
        if self.update_callback:
            self.update_callback()


class PositionFrame(tk.LabelFrame):
    """
    A LabelFrame that has two LabelFrames which has Scales.
    """

    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.LabelFrame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self._create_widgets()
        self._layout()


    def _create_widgets(self):
        self.line = SliderFrame(self, orient='vertical', text="line=")
        self.column = SliderFrame(self, orient='horizontal', text="column=")
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Label")


    def _layout(self):
        self.line.grid(sticky='ns', row=0, column=0, rowspan=2)
        self.column.grid(sticky='ew', row=0, column=1, columnspan=2)
        self.label.grid(sticky='nsew', row=1, column=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)


class SliderFrame(tk.LabelFrame):
    """
    A LabelFrame that encapsulates a Scale.
    """

    def __init__(self, master, orient, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.LabelFrame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.slider = tk.Scale(self, orient=orient)
        self.slider.pack(fill='both', expand=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    demo = Demo(root, text="text.get(start, end=None)")

    with open(__file__) as f:
        demo.text.insert('1.0', f.read())
    demo.text.update_stats()
    demo.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5):

I faced the problem of gettng entire text from Text widget and following solution worked for me :

```
txt.get(1.0,END)
```

Where 1.0 means first line, zeroth character (ie before the first!)
is the starting position and END is the ending position.

Thanks to Alan Gauld in this [link](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2005-February/035669.html)

Comment: The first argument should be in quotes.  It is not a float number, it is a string with two integers and a dot separator.

Comment: That link had that error, and even the source for that link was in error. Here's a better link: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2005-February/035667.html

Comment: This would give exactly the same problem written about in the question. Plus, technically, the index `1.0` is not correct. Indexes are strings, not floating point numbers. Tkinter is a bit forgiving in this regard so `1.0` and `"1.0"` are treated the same but something like `1.10` is definitely not the same as `"1.10"`.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a better way-

```
variable1=StringVar() # Value saved here

def search():
  print(variable1.get())
  return ''

ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=variable1).grid(column=2, row=1)

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="label").grid(column=1, row=1)

ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Search", command=search).grid(column=2, row=13)
```

On pressing the button, the value in the text field would get printed.
But make sure You import the ttk separately.

The **full code** for a **basic application** is-

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root=Tk()
mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="10 10 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


variable1=StringVar() # Value saved here

def search():
  print(variable1.get())
  return ''

ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=variable1).grid(column=2, row=1)

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="label").grid(column=1, row=1)

ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Search", command=search).grid(column=2, row=13)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that creating a simple extension of Text and turning `text` into a property is the cleanest way to go. You can then stick that extension in some file that you always import, and use it instead of the original `Text` widget. This way, instead of having to remember, write, repeat, etc all the hoops tkinter makes you jump through to do the simplest things, you have a butt-simple interface that can be reused in any project. You can do this for `Entry`, as well, but the syntax is slightly different.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()    
    
class Text(tk.Text):
    @property
    def text(self) -> str:
        return self.get('1.0', 'end-1c')
        
    @text.setter
    def text(self, value) -> None:
        self.replace('1.0', 'end-1c', value)
        
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Text.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

#Entry version of the same concept as above      
class Entry(tk.Entry):
    @property
    def text(self) -> str:
        return self.get()
        
    @text.setter
    def text(self, value) -> None:
        self.delete(0, 'end')
        self.insert(0, value)
        
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Entry.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)      
      
textbox = Text(root)
textbox.grid()

textbox.text = "this is text" #set
print(textbox.text)           #get  

entry = Entry(root)
entry.grid()

entry.text = 'this is text'   #set
print(entry.text)             #get

root.mainloop()
```

---

In regards to the comment by Bryan Oakley, I have an updated solution. The Text widget `insert`, `delete`, `replace`, and `get` methods can be rewired to a slice or key (respectively). By doing so we can also slightly expand what an acceptable Text index is, and default some indices depending on what you have implied.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from typing import Any

class Text(tk.Text):
    @property
    def text(self) -> str:
        return self.get('1.0', tk.END)
        
    @text.setter
    def text(self, value:str) -> None:
        self.replace('1.0', tk.END, value)

    # test and get indices
    def __getindices(self, key) -> tuple|None:
        def indice(idx:str|int|float) -> str:
            # allow int indices
            if (idx := f'{idx}').isdigit():
                idx = f'{idx}.0'
            
            try: 
                self.get(idx, idx)
            except tk.TclError: 
                print(f'({idx}) is not a valid index')
                idx = ''
                
            return idx
            
        if isinstance(key, slice):
            start = indice(key.start or '1.0')
            stop  = indice(key.stop  or 'end-1c')
            if start and stop:
                return start, stop
        elif start := indice(key):
            return start, None
            
        return None

    # replace if slice, insert if single indice      
    def __setitem__(self, key, value) -> None:
        if idx := self.__getindices(key):
            start, stop = idx
            if start:
                if stop: self.replace(start, stop, value)
                else   : self.insert(start, value)
                return
            
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        
    # get slice range
    def __getitem__(self, key) -> Any:
        if not (None in (idx := self.__getindices(key))):
            return self.get(*idx)
            
        return super().__getitem__(key)
      
    # delete slice range
    def __delitem__(self, key) -> None:
        if not (None in (idx := self.__getindices(key))):
            self.delete(*idx)
            return
            
        super().__delitem__(key)
```

###### usage

```py
root = tk.Tk()
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

text = Text(root)
text.text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
text.grid(sticky='nswe')

def deleter(event=None):
    del text['1.0':'1.3']
    return "break"
    
def printer(event=None):
    print(text['insert':'insert+3c'])
    return "break"
    
def setter(event=None):
    text['insert':'insert+3c'] = 'xyz'     # replace in slice range
    text[:]                    = 'abcdef'  # replace - ['1.0':'end-1c'] is implied
    text[1.12]                 = 'abcdef'  # insert at 1.12 - floats allowed
    text[1:'1.end']            = 'xyzabc'  # replace in slice range - ints allowed
    return "break"

text.bind('<KeyPress-Delete>', deleter)
text.bind('<KeyPress-End>', printer)
text.bind('<KeyPress-Insert>', setter)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Using the setter is good if all you need is the full contents of the text widget. However, it is often the case that you need to extract only part of the text (for example, when cutting a word, sentence, or paragraph). That's why those "hoops" exist.

Comment: @BryanOakley - I can easily agree with you regarding `tk.Text` ... not so much regarding `tk.Entry`.

Answer (score 1):

I did come also in search of how to get input data from the Text widget. Regarding the problem with a new line on the end of the string. You can just use .strip() since it is a Text widget that is always a string.

Also, I'm sharing code where you can see how you can create multiply Text widgets and save them in the dictionary as form data, and then by clicking the submit button get that form data and do whatever you want with it. I hope it helps others. It should work in any 3.x python and probably will work in 2.7 also.

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

class SimpleTkForm(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()

    def myform(self):
        self.root.title('My form')
        frame = Frame(self.root, pady=10)
        form_data = dict()
        form_fields = ['username', 'password', 'server name', 'database name']
        cnt = 0
        for form_field in form_fields:
            Label(frame, text=form_field, anchor=NW).grid(row=cnt,column=1, pady=5, padx=(10, 1), sticky="W")
            textbox = Text(frame, height=1, width=15)
            form_data.update({form_field: textbox})
            textbox.grid(row=cnt,column=2, pady=5, padx=(3,20))
            cnt += 1

        conn_test = partial(self.test_db_conn, form_data=form_data)
        Button(frame, text='Submit', width=15, command=conn_test).grid(row=cnt,column=2, pady=5, padx=(3,20))
        frame.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

    def test_db_conn(self, form_data):
        data = {k:v.get('1.0', END).strip() for k,v in form_data.items()}
        # validate data or do anything you want with it
        print(data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    api = SimpleTkForm()
    api.myform()
```

Comment: Calling `strip` could end up deleting more than just a single trailing newline if the widget has several blank lines. If the goal is to get exactly what the user entered, this isn't the right solution.

Comment: You really helped me I love this snippet of code

Answer (score -3):

Lets say that you have a `Text` widget called `my_text_widget`.

To **get** input from the `my_text_widget` you can use the `get` function.

Let's assume that you have imported `tkinter`.
Lets define `my_text_widget` first, lets make it just a simple text widget.

```
my_text_widget = Text(self)
```

To **get** input from a `text` widget you need to use the `get` function, both, `text` and `entry` widgets have this.

```
input = my_text_widget.get()
```

The reason we save it to a variable is to use it in the further process, for example, testing for what's the input.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The `Text` widget `get` method requires at least one argument.