# How to get entry from Text Box. Python

Tags: python, textbox, tkinter

I have made a text box and a button. When the button is clicked it should display the content within the text box.

I have followed a tutorial but I couldn't get it to work, so I then came on here and found a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824163/how-to-get-the-input-from-the-tkinter-text-box-widget) where someone else had this problem, but I still couldn't figure out why mine gives this error.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Here is the code.

```
def send_feedback(*args):
    feedback = self.MyEntryBox.get("0.0",'END-1c')
    print(feedback)

self.MyEntryBox = Text(SWH, width=80, height=20, bd=5, fg="#0094FF",relief = RIDGE).place(x=200,y=400)
SubmitButton = Button(SWH, text="Submit", fg="White", bg="#0094FF", font=("Grobold",20),command=send_feedback).pack()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning `None` to `SubmitButton` and `self.MyEntryBox`, because that is what `widget.pack()` and `widget.place()` return.

Instead, make it two separate lines for each widget, so you assign the widget to an accessible name *then* position the widget in the UI:

```
self.MyEntryBox = Text(SWH, width=80, height=20, bd=5, fg="#0094FF", relief = RIDGE)
self.MyEntryBox.place(x=200, y=400)
SubmitButton = Button(SWH, text="Submit", fg="White", bg="#0094FF", 
                      font=("Grobold", 20), command=send_feedback)
SubmitButton.pack()
```

Also, `SubmitButton` should probably be an instance attribute like `MyEntryBox`, and it would probably be easier if you `pack`ed or `place`d everything, rather than trying to mix and match.

Comment: Great Stuff! Thanks very much. Concerning the .pack() and .place() I am using .place throughout my program just while i was getting this page working i just packed the button for simplicity. Thanks again.