# How do I store a text entry as a variable in Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, messagebox

So.....

I want my program to launch a Tkinter GUI Window, which gives the user text boxes to enter values as strings or as integers.....
The code below does that

```
    from Tkinter import *


    def add_text():
       label1 = Label(root, text="You have entered the information to the average speed checker")
       label1.pack()

    root = Tk()
    root.title("Average Speed Checker")
    root.geometry("450x165")

    veh_reg_label = Label(root, text="Vehicle Registration:")
    veh_reg_label.pack()

    veh_reg_text_box = Entry(root, bd=1)
    veh_reg_text_box.pack()

    distance_label = Label(root, text="Distance")
    distance_label.pack()

    distance_text_box = Entry(root, bd=1)
    distance_text_box.pack()

    time_label = Label(root, text="Time")
    time_label.pack()

    time_text_box = Entry(root, bd=1)
    time_text_box.pack()

    enter_button = Button(root, text="Enter", command=add_text)
    enter_button.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

However.....
There is one problem: I can't seem to find a (simple  ;) ) way of storing this text entry as a variable, which means that I am not able to continue with my program by making it calculate if a car is over a certain speed when travelling a distance of road etc etc.....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824163/how-to-get-the-input-from-the-tkinter-text-box-widget

Comment: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
def retrieve_input():
    global vehicle_registration
    global vehicle_time
    global vehicle_distance
    vehicle_registration = veh_reg_text_box.get()
    vehicle_time = time_text_box.get()
    vehicle_distance = distance_text_box.get()
    number_checker()
```

Comment: how is that different from my answer and why the need of `global`?

Comment: It was just a little variation from yours; thanks for your help :)

Comment: I found I didn't need the 'self', the globals are because of the use of the variables and this and other functions randomly throughout the program; it's pretty messy right now ;)

Comment: OK, I get it, but the `global` things really need to get "cleaned". :)

Comment: And you should mark the answer, so it is shown as solved.

Comment: The indentation of your answer is incorrect. It can't run as posted.

Answer (score 2):

Use this in your add_text() funtion:

```
 user_entry = self.text_box_name.get()
```