# Save text held presumably in a textbox in a Tkinter Python 3 Program to a textfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, textbox

This is my code with some bits removed, this sends output to a "Notes.txt" textfile but it normally just sends a decimal point followed by random decimal digits.  Hopefully a beginner mistake.  Code snippets below:

```
class Window (Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()

    def init_window (self):#This sets up the 'Window Frame'
        self.master.title("'Joe Banks' - Witty name to follow")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        #Irrelevant File Menus and buttons removed
        #Adds Textbox for typing Notes etc.
        blankTextbox = Text(app, width = 30, height=4, font=("CenturyGothic",18))
        blankTextbox.place(x=270, y=550, anchor="c")
```

Then in a different procedure:

```
def saveTextboxToFile(self):
    fileContent = str(Text(app, width = 30, height=4, font=("CenturyGothic",18)))
    file = open("Notes.txt", "w")
    file.write(fileContent)
    file.close()
```

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14824164/6220679).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the input from the Tkinter Text Box Widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824163/how-to-get-the-input-from-the-tkinter-text-box-widget)