# Display IMAGE and TEXTBOX simultanously in a "form" with PYTHON

Tags: python, image, opencv, tkinter, textbox

[Here what I'd like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0XOT.jpg)

I'm new in PYTHON. I'm trying to display IMAGE and TEXTBOX simultaneously in a "Form" with PYTHON.

My problem: Image is not visible on the screen. How to solve that problem?

Thanks,

My code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

#This creates the main window of an application
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("SEE image and ENTER its information")
window.geometry("600x400")
window.configure(background='grey')

# Create textbox in window
text_widget = tk.Text(window)
text_widget.insert('insert',"Enter image information here")
text_widget.pack(anchor = "w", padx = 50, pady = 50)



#Creates a tkinter-compatible photo image.
path = "Picture.jpg"
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))

#The Label widget is a standard tkinter widget used to display a text or 
image on the screen.
panel = tk.Label(window, image = img)

#The Pack geometry manager packs widgets in rows or columns.
#panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "no")
panel.pack()


#Start the GUI
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

#This creates the main window of an application
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("SEE image and ENTER its information")
window.geometry("600x400")
window.configure(background='grey')

#Creates a tkinter-compatible photo image.
path = "Picture.jpg"
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))

#The Label widget is a standard tkinter widget used to display a text or image on the screen.
panel = tk.Label(window, image = img)

# Create textbox in window
text_widget = tk.Text(panel)
text_widget.insert('insert',"Enter image information here")
text_widget.pack(anchor = "w", padx = 50, pady = 50)


#The Pack geometry manager packs widgets in rows or columns.
#panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "no")
panel.pack()


#Start the GUI
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: By the way, is there any way to separate image and textbox? Thanks!

Comment: You mean having two windows: one for image and the other for text or do you want a transparent textbox through which the background can be seen

Comment: I mean one window - image on top and textbox at bottom of window so I can input information for image

Answer (score 1):

If that's the idea, do you wish to display information to the user or for user to enter information?

Assuming the latter, here is something.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("SEE image and ENTER its information")
window.geometry("600x400") # You can drop this line if you want.
window.configure(background='grey')

path = "Picture.jpg"
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
panel = tk.Label(window, image = img)

txtVar = tk.StringVar(None)
usrIn = tk.Entry(window, textvariable = txtVar, width = 90)
usrIn.grid(row = 50, column = 60)

usrIn.pack()
panel.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

The`txtVar` can be used for accepting info from user. You may also have to use the `Button` feature if needed.
Here is nice [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824163/how-to-get-the-input-from-the-tkinter-text-box-widget).