# nltk comparing tokens ( == returning false when "true")

Tags: python, nltk, tokenize

I think I may be fundamentally confused about something in python or nltk.  I'm generating a list of tokens from a paper abstract, and attempting to see if a search word is contained by the tokens.  I do know about concordance, but it doesn't work well with my intended use of the comparison.

Here is my code:

```
def tokenize(text):
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text.get_text())
    return tokens

def search_abstract_single_word(tokens, keyword):
    match = 0
    for token in tokens:
        if token == keyword:
            match += 1
    return match

def search_file_single_word(abstract_list, keyword):
    matches = list()
    for item in abstract_list:
        tokens = tokenize(item)
        match = search_abstract_single_word(tokens, keyword)
        matches.append(match)
    return matches
```

I've confirmed that the tokens and keyword being passed in are correct, but match (and thus the entire list of matches) always evaluates zero.  I was under the understanding word_tokenize returns an array of strings, so I don't see why, for example, when token = computer and keyword = computer, token == keyword does not return true and increment match.

EDIT: In a standalone class/main method this code does appear to work.  However, the code is being called from a tkinter window like so:

```
self.keyword = ""
....
self.keywords_box = Text(self.Frame2)
....
self.Submit = Button(master)
self.Submit.configure(command=self.submit)
....
#triggered by submit button
def submit(self):
    self.keywords += self.keywords_box.get("1.0", END)

#triggered by run button after keyword saved
def run(self):
    search_input = self.keywords
    ....
    #use pandas to read excel file, create abstracts, and store
    ....
    matches = search_file_single_word(abstract_list, search_input)
    for match in matches:
        self.output_box.insert(END, match)
        self.output_box.insert(END, '\n')
```

I had assumed because print(keyword) was outputting correctly if I inserted it into search_file_single_word, that the value was passed correctly, but is it actually just passing the tkinter property along and refusing to evaluate it vs the token?

Comment: Is the keyword you are looking for already tokenized ?

Comment: It seems to work to me: https://pastebin.com/0xX7q0am

Comment: @J.Zagdoun I tried tokenizing the keyword, it did not make a difference.

Comment: @Neil Could it work by itself but not for me because the keyword passed is a tkinter window property?

Comment: Wait what do you mean by betokening the keyword?  If you tokenizing the keyword then you're comparing a list to a string...

Comment: @Neil I had simply run tokenize on the keyword, which would just return a single token (I think) after JZ asked.  Didn't change anything so I reverted it.

It was related to the GUI after all though.  After re-reading some pages on text box get(), END will place a new line character at the end of keyword, which was invisible in my test prints but would in fact cause an inequality.  Changed it to 'end - 1c' from another stack exchange post and it runs fine now

Answer (score 0):

Moral of the story, be careful with options.  Using textbox.get("1.0", END) will insert a newline character.  string != string\n.  Solution found in answer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824163/how-to-get-the-input-from-the-tkinter-text-box-widget)