# How to store the input from the text box in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, tkinter, textbox

I want to make a program that show me the divisors of the number introduced in a text box using python tkinter GUI and store the results into a plain text file.

I don't how to get the value from the text box. I understood that is something linked with `get()` , I read something but I still don't get it.

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

def create_file():
    file_object = open("C:/Users/valis/Desktop/Divisors.txt","w+")


def evaluate():
    show_after= Label(text= "Check your Desktop !")
    show_after.pack(pady=2, anchor=SW)
    create_file()


#Windows size and Title
window = Tk()
window.title("Show Divisors")
window.geometry("300x100")

message = Label(window, text="Enter a number : ")
message.pack(pady=2, anchor=NW)

textbox_input = Text(window,height=1, width=11)
textbox_input.pack(padx= 2,pady= 2, anchor=NW)

window.mainloop()
```

The code isn't complete, so what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you will use the **get()** function but with some additional attributes.

If we have a text box **textbox_input**, then you can return its input using this line:

```
test_input = textbox_input.get("1.0",END)
```

The first part, **"1.0"** means that the input should be read from line one, character zero (ie: the very first character). **END** is an imported constant which is set to the string "end". The **END** part means to read until the end of the text box is reached.

Reference: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14824164/5426539).