# How to get the text out of a scrolledtext widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, gettext

I am new to the `tkinter` python module. I try to do a project. I learned something new about the menus and I'm trying to make a little UI project that allows the user to write something in a scrolled text widget and then save it (using the `sys` module).

I've already tried some things that worked at buttons. For example `.get()` but it didn't work. I also tried the `["text"]` method.

```
import tkinter, sys

root = tkinter.Tk()

class saveProject:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.textFrame = tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.master, width=100, bd=10, relief="raised")
        self.textFrame.pack()
     def save(self):
        #self.saveText = self.textFrame.get()
        self.saveText = self.textFrame["text"]

project = saveProject(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The problem is, as I already said, I don't know how to get the text out of a `tkinter.scrolledtext.ScrolledText` widget.

Comment: `tkinter` doesn't have a `scrolledtext.ScrolledText` or a `ScrolledText` widget that I know of—so it's unclear what you are talking about. It is possible to make a regular `Text` scrollable on the other hand.

Comment: @martineau have a look here:
 [https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.scrolledtext.html] I think this answer might help you: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824163/how-to-get-the-input-from-the-tkinter-text-box-widget]. Could this question be considered a duplicate?

Comment: @Valentino: That first docs link in your comment results in: `404 Not Found`. The other one to a possible duplicate might be one — **if** that's what the OP is really talking about.

Comment: @martineau ops, let me try again with the link. [https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.scrolledtext.html ]. If the scrolledtext Gigi is speaking about is this, it's just a tkinter.Text class with a scrollbar.

Comment: @Valentino: That link works better. I haven't ever used the `tix` extension widgets before (and won 't since its use has been "Deprecated since version 3.6"). The documentation of this, like most everythng else in `tkinter`, isn't great either. I suppose one could look at the source code a figure-out how to do this...

Comment: @Valentino: BTW, the OP's code doesn't get very far the way it is: `AttributeError: module 'tkinter' has no attribute 'scrolledtext'`—so it has other problems, as well.

Comment: @martineau you're right. My guess is that the `scrolledtext` module is not loaded when you import tkinter. At least I need to explicitly add `from tkinter import scrolledtext` to make it working. However this not really answer the OP question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, out of curiosity I tried what described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824163/how-to-get-the-input-from-the-tkinter-text-box-widget) (same link in my comment to the OP question). It works also for the `scrolledtext`.

```
import tkinter, sys
from tkinter import scrolledtext

root = tkinter.Tk()

class saveProject:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.textFrame = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.master, width=100, bd=10, relief="raised")
        self.textFrame.pack()
        self.saveb = tkinter.Button(self.master, text="Save", command= lambda : self.save())
        self.saveb.pack()

    def save(self):
        cur_inp = self.textFrame.get("1.0", tkinter.END)
        fl = open("output.txt", "w")
        fl.write(cur_inp)

project = saveProject(root)
root.mainloop()
```

I've added a save button at the bottom of the `ScrolledText` widget. The widget content is saved inside the `output.txt` area.

Answer (score 5):

`help(ScrolledText)` indicates it's a subclass of the `tkinter.Text` widget, which apparently means that the way to get the text from it is the same — via its `get()` method using "Text widget indices" (here's some [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20190315202523id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/text-index.html) about them).

Below is an example that gets all of the text in the widget (I added a <kbd>Save text</kbd> `Button` to test the `save()` method):

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText

class SaveProject:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.textFrame = ScrolledText(self.master, width=100, bd=10, relief="raised")
        self.textFrame.pack()
        # Added for testing.
        self.save_btn = tk.Button(self.master, text='Save text', command=self.save)
        self.save_btn.pack()

    def save(self):
        self.saveText = self.textFrame.get('1.0', tk.END)  # Get all text in widget.
        print('self.saveText:', self.saveText)

root = tk.Tk()
project = SaveProject(root)
root.mainloop()
```