# Question about retrieving text from Tkinter textbox widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I was searching for how to retrieve inputs from Tkinter Textbox widget and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824163/how-to-get-the-input-from-the-tkinter-text-box-widget). After reading the answer and following the code, I got some few questions.

1st
In the answer, most of them they created a method `retrieve_input()` and used that method inside the Button widget command. The `retrieve_input()`method is specific for one textbox. If I have several textboxes and wants to receive the inputs from all of them, do I have to create each methods for individual textboxes? Is there a way to create a general method to receive the inputs from different textboxes? or do I have to create a separate class or modules (if so how to do it?)

2nd
I tried the code with pycharm but it did not show the input value in the console even after I pressed 'ok' button 
Answered with [Why is Button parameter “command” executed when declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767228/why-is-button-parameter-command-executed-when-declared)

3rd
if I get rid of `"1.0", "end-1c"` it shows `TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index1'`. When I look up that error, it says that I did not initiate the starting value. But I saw many other examples in the internet that did not put any parameters inside the get(). Also I thought if I do not put any parameters, the get() will automatically get the first characters. Which part am I understanding wrong?

Thank you  Reblochon Masque for giving me the link for answer 2. But I still don't get question 1 and 3

```
from tkinter import *

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Youtube Converter")

def retrieve_input():
    inputValue = textBox.get("1.0", "end-1c")
    print(inputValue)

label = Label(root, text="type url")
label.grid(row=0, column=0)

textBox = Text(root, height=2, width=10)
textBox.grid(row=0, column=1)

btn = Button(root, height = 1, width=15, text = "ok", command = retrieve_input())
btn.grid(row=1, column=1)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: remove the parenthesis after `retrieve_input`:      `btn = Button(root, height = 1, width=15, text = "ok", command = retrieve_input)` <-- here

Comment: Thank you  Reblochon Masque for the answer. May you also help me answer Q1 and 2?

Comment: 3rd question: you are confusing `tk.Entry` with `tk.Text `; the former does not require indexing of the values to be retrieved. The first question requires more than a comment to answer - please ask a new question, and feel free to ping me when it is done.

Comment: I posted the question but did not know how to ping you from there. So I leave a comment @ReblochonMasque.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57227812/about-retrieving-method-in-tkinter the link

Comment: Thank you - @BrianOakley correctly replied already, you should upvote and accept his answer.