# base64 encoding image; binascii.Error: Invalid base64-encoded

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

as a project for a course, I'm developing an image coder/decoder using python, but it seems I  got a little stuck and I would really apreciate getting some help

The error I'm getting is:

```
runfile('D:/Documentos/Python/Proyecto_Final/Main.py', wdir='D:/Documentos/Python/Proyecto_Final')
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:\Documentos\Python\Proyecto_Final\Main.py", line 32, in decode64
    imagen.write(base64.decodebytes(baset.encode()))
  File "C:\...\anaconda3\lib\base64.py", line 546, in decodebytes
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (1) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4
```

My code is:

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import base64

def browseBtn():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    texto.insert(0, filename)

def convbase64():
    path = str(texto.get())
    imagen = open(path, 'rb')
    leeimg = imagen.read()
    codigo64 = base64.encodebytes(leeimg)
    texto2.insert("1.0", codigo64)

def decode64():
    myFormats = [('JPEG / JFIF','*.jpg'),\
                     ('Portable Network Graphics','*.png'),\
                     ('Windows Bitmap','*.bmp'),('CompuServer GIF','*.gif'),]
    baset = texto2.get(1.0)
    filepath = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=myFormats)
    imagen = open(filepath, 'wb')
    imagen.write(base64.decodebytes(baset.encode()))
    imagen.close()

ventana = Tk()
ventana.title("Convertidor imagen a Base64")
ventana.geometry("800x480")
letrero = Label(ventana, text = "Imagen:")
texto = Entry(ventana, width = 100)
buscarImg = Button(ventana, text = "Elegir", command=browseBtn)
letrero2 = Label(ventana, text = "codigo base64:")
texto2 = Text(width = 75, height = 1)
btnconvertir = Button(ventana, text = "Codificar", command=convbase64)
btndecodificar = Button(ventana, text = "decodificar", command=decode64)
letrero.place(x = 32, y = 32)
letrero2.place(x = 16, y = 64)
texto.place(x = 114, y = 35)
texto2.place(x = 114, y = 69)
buscarImg.place(x = 724, y = 32)
btnconvertir.place(x = 724, y = 64)
btndecodificar.place (x = 724, y = 96)

ventana.mainloop()
```

I'm using anaconda's Spyder 3.7

Comment: @Ruzihm I am not Python-er, so I am not able to understand this typo. Some typos are worth an answer, are you sure this one doesn't need further explanation?

Comment: hi, so, i tried doing it but it didn't work, i still get the same error

Comment: _but it seems I got a little stuck and I would really apreciate getting some help_ Help with what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `Text.get` to get more than one character, you need to give it an end position. You can use the special string `"end"` for this, but ignoring the last newline character that tkinter adds with `"end-1c"`:

```
baset = texto2.get("1.0", "end-1c")
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48477519/1092820) for more information

Comment: `"end"` will get one more character out than was put in, because tkinter automatically adds a trailing newline. If you want to get out exactlly what was put in you should use `"end-1c"`.