# variable filename does not exist when it does

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, save

For some reason, I cannot get my code to work — it shows me errors that the variable doesn't exist when it does.

Here is my code:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox as msg
from tkinter import filedialog #https://pythonspot.com/tk-file-dialogs/
def save():
    global filename
    try: #here, if variable `filename' does not exist, we will ask for a filename. if it does exist, we'll use it. kind of like how a normal text editor makes you save as the same file until you click "New".
        yolo = filename
        del yolo
        keepTheFilename = True
    except:
        keepTheFilename = False
    from os.path import expanduser
    home = expanduser("~")
    if keepTheFilename is True:
        filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir=home, title="Saving file")
    #print("Saving to  %s" % filename, end="\r")
    theText = text.get(0.0, "end-1c") #https://stackoverflow.com/a/14824164/9654083
    with open(filename, "w") as theFile:
        theFile.write(theText)
        print("Saving to  %s, done." % filename)
    slate.title(filename)
def openFile():
    from os.path import expanduser
    home = expanduser("~")
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=home, title="Select file to open")
    with open(filename, "r") as theFile:
        theText = theFile.read()
        text.delete(0.0, END)
        text.insert(END, theText)
    slate.title(filename)
def deleteAll():
    text.delete(0.0, END)
    slate.title("slate")
    del filename
def hello():
    msg.showinfo("About", "slate is a decent plain-text editor. Thanks for using!")
    Label(slate, text="To-Dos: - add \"staying on file\" (instead of having to type the filename over and over again; - copy-paste functions; - and more!").pack()

slate = Tk() #set up window. `slate' is now the name of the window, internally
slate.title("slate") #set up window. `slate' is now the word in the title bar
scrollbar = Scrollbar(slate, orient=VERTICAL) #set up scrollbar
scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill = Y ) #vertical

text = Text(slate, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
text.pack()
scrollbar.config( command = text.yview )
w = Button(slate, text="Save", command=save)
w2 = Button(slate, text="Open", command=openFile)

w.pack(padx=5, pady=10, side=LEFT)
w2.pack(padx=5, pady=10, side=LEFT)

mainloop()
```

And this is the error when I run `save()` (by clicking the save button):

```
File "slateGUI.py", line 17, in save
    with open(filename, "w") as theFile:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'filename' referenced before assignment
```

If I add `global filename`:

```
File "slateGUI.py", line 19, in save
    print("Saving to  %s" % filename, end="\r")
NameError: name 'filename' is not defined
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Did you define filename anywhere?

Comment: Yes, when you either save or open a file. But after that, just like most text-editors, it will not ask you for a path unless you open a different file or click "New".

Comment: I just added more code. So you should now be able to see the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to @AnnZen's great answer, I figured it out:

```py
def save():
    try: # If the exception occurs, keepTheFilename = False
        yolo = filename
        del yolo
        keepTheFilename = True
    except:
        keepTheFilename = False
    from os.path import expanduser
    home = expanduser("~")
    if keepTheFilename is not True: # If the exception occurred, this if statement will not be launched, hence filename haven't been defined
        filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir=home, title="Saving file")
    else:
        global filename
    print("Saving to  %s" % filename, end="\r")
    theText = text.get(0.0, "end-1c") #https://stackoverflow.com/a/14824164/9654083
    with open(filename, "w") as theFile:
        theFile.write(theText)
        print("Saving to  %s, done." % filename)
    slate.title(filename)
```

The logic: If `keepTheFilename` is not defined, it will ask for the path. However, if it is defined, it will save to that original path (using `global filename` in the `else` block).

There IS a syntax warning (from `global filename`):

```
slateGUI.py:16: SyntaxWarning: name 'filename' is assigned to before global declaration
  global filename
```

Thanks so much AnnZen!

Comment: I _would_ mark this as the answer, but it says I can only do it tomorrow. :(

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. The SyntaxWarning turned into a SyntaxError (so I fixed it) but now the variable `filename` just doesn't exist in the global scope...even though I declare it.

Answer (score 1):

If the exception occurs, `keepTheFilename = False`. If `keepTheFilename = False`, the `if` statement will not be launched, hence filename won't be defined.

```
def save():
    try: # If the exception occurs, keepTheFilename = False
        yolo = filename
        del yolo
        keepTheFilename = True
    except:
        keepTheFilename = False
    from os.path import expanduser
    home = expanduser("~")
    if keepTheFilename is True: # If the exception occurred, this if statement will not be launched, hence filename haven't been defined
        filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir=home, title="Saving file")
    print("Saving to  %s" % filename, end="\r")
    theText = text.get(0.0, "end-1c") #https://stackoverflow.com/a/14824164/9654083
    with open(filename, "w") as theFile:
        theFile.write(theText)
        print("Saving to  %s, done." % filename)
    slate.title(filename)
```