# How to get user input and pass that input into function with Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to get text that a user has inputted and then alternate the case of the text - e.g. If you input 'hello' it will output 'HeLlO'

[This is what my Tkinter window looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgN9b.png)

Here is the code I have:

```
from itertools import cycle
from tkinter import *


win = Tk()
win.title("Alternator")
win.resizable(0,0)


def Alternate():

   func = cycle([str.upper, str.lower])
   result = ''.join(next(func)(c) for c in entry.get() if c != '  ')
   return result




l1 = Label(win, text="Enter text: ")
entry = Text(win, width=50, height = 3, wrap=WORD)
button = Button(win, text="Alternator", width=20)
l2 = Label(win, text="Alternated text:")
output = Text(win, width=50, height=3, wrap=WORD)

l1.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, sticky=W)
entry.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=(0,10))
button.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2, pady=5)
l2.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5, sticky=W)
output.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=(0,10))

button.configure(command=Alternate)

win.mainloop()
```

What is the correct way to go about this problem? I have seen various questions related, but none that cover this at a basic level

Comment: Read up on [The Tkinter Text Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm)

Comment: The text widget documentation tells you everything you need to answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the text you need to give 2 parameters to `entry.get()`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14824164/5124383) is a nice answer explaining which. After that you have to set the text with `output.insert()`. You can change this depending on what you want to happen, right now it adds a new line with the alternated text from above.

```
def Alternate():
   func = cycle([str.upper, str.lower])
   result = ''.join(next(func)(c) for c in entry.get("1.0",END) if c != '  ')
   output.insert(END,result)
   #return result
```

Answer (score -1):

I have some important tips and facts here. First of all, instead of using the `Text()` widget, you can use the `Entry()` widget as you are only giving simple words as input. Then you can get the characters inside the Entry like this

```
variable = name_of_entry.get()
```

Then you can alternate the casing of the letters and display the jumble-cased letters as simple text in `Label()`.

```
name_of_label.configure(text=variable)
```