# TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index1'

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a super simple email client. This will enable me to send emails from school to my home computer because they have outlook and gmail blocked. When i try to run it, it says: TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index1' I have replaced my email and password with asterix's for security purposes. Thanks in advance :)

Heres my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from email.message import EmailMessage
import smtplib

window=Tk()
window.title('Email Client')
window.geometry('200x275')

textbox2=Text(window,width=20,height=10,bg='light grey')
label2=Label(window,text='Message')
textbox1=Text(window,width=20,height=1,bg='light grey')
label1=Label(window,text='Subject')

def email_alert(subject, body, to):
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(body)
    msg['subject'] = subject
    msg['to'] = to

    user = "*******************"
    msg['from'] = user
    password = "*************"

    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(user, password)
    server.send_message(msg)

    server.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def Send():
        dialog = textbox1.get()
        subject = textbox2.get()
        email_alert(subject, dialog, "******************")

label1.pack()
textbox1.pack()
label2.pack()
textbox2.pack()

button1=Button(window,text='Send Email',width=10,height=1, command=Send)
button1.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On your `send()` function, you need to add `get()` parameters.

```py
dialog = textbox1.get("1.0",'end-1c')
subject = textbox2.get("1.0",'end-1c')
```

The first part, `"1.0"` means that the input should be read from line one, character zero.

The `end-1c` is divided in 2 parts:

1. `end`: Read until the end of the text.
2. `1c`: Remove 1 character starting from the end.

It deletes the last character to remove that last `\n` so your e-mail doesn't end with an extra line.

Answer (score 2):

Use `textbox1.get("1.0",'end-1c')` instead. This should give you the text inside the textbox.

The explanation can be found here: [How to get the input from the Tkinter Text Widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824163/how-to-get-the-input-from-the-tkinter-text-widget)

Answer (score 0):

the error happened because the `.get` method requires at least 1 parameter.
To get the contents, you have to use `.get("1.0",END)`

try

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
from email.message import EmailMessage
import smtplib

window=Tk()
window.title('Email Client')
window.geometry('200x275')

textbox2=Text(window,width=20,height=10,bg='light grey')
label2=Label(window,text='Message')
textbox1=Text(window,width=20,height=1,bg='light grey')
label1=Label(window,text='Subject')

def email_alert(subject, body, to):
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(body)
    msg['subject'] = subject
    msg['to'] = to

    user = "*******************"
    msg['from'] = user
    password = "*************"

    server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(user, password)
    server.send_message(msg)

    server.quit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def Send():
        dialog = textbox1.get("1.0",END)
        subject = textbox2.get("1.0",END)
        email_alert(subject, dialog, "******************")

label1.pack()
textbox1.pack()
label2.pack()
textbox2.pack()

button1=Button(window,text='Send Email',width=10,height=1, command=Send)
button1.pack()

window.mainloop()
```