# searching in strings from tk-inter text fails

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-text

Why does the search fail when taking a string from a tk-inter text box?
The search works fine if I define the keyword as a string.

Minimal example:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
string="banana\napplepie\napple\n"

def searchcall():
 
    textboxcontent=textExample.get("1.0","end")
    keyword=filterbox.get("1.0","end")
    keyword="apple" # search works as expected

    print("keyword",keyword)
    print("is keyword in textbox",keyword in textboxcontent)
    for elem in textboxcontent.split():
        print("seaching for",keyword,"in",elem,keyword in elem)
 
        

textExample=tk.Text(root, height=10)
textExample.insert(1.0,string)
textExample.pack()
filterbox=tk.Text(root, height=1)
filterbox.insert(1.0,"apple")
filterbox.pack()
btnRead=tk.Button(root, height=1, width=11, text="search", 
                    command=searchcall)

btnRead.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you want a single line input, use `Entry` instead of `Text` widget for `filterbox`.

Comment: The solution is to change `filterbox`  to `filterbox.insert(1.0,"apple\n")`. The Text end tag inserts a line feed on the last entry. Now it works!

Comment: @Derek the idea is that the user would provide the contents via GUI. the insert statements are  to provide an example.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that tk inter appends a line break "\n" at the end when you read the contents of a widget.
Remove the "\n" at the end of the strings. For example, with [strip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

```
keyword=filterbox.get("1.0","end").strip()
```

you can also choose to read everything but the last character like this ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14824164/3503111)):

```
keyword=filterbox.get("1.0",'end-1c')
```