# python tkinter text: the widget always contain a newline character

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm using a `tkinter.Text` widget, and I noticed that it cannot be empty (not contain text). I tried:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

textbox = tk.Text(root)

print("ini")
#textbox.delete("1.0", tk.END)
#textbox.insert(tk.INSERT, "ey")
#print(textbox.get("1.0", tk.END))
print(repr(textbox.get("1.0", tk.END)))
print("end")

root.mainloop()
```

And I get:

```
ini
'\n'
end
```

Is there any way to remove that character, `textbox.delete("1.0", tk.END)` doesn't work. Of course, I can always do `textbox.get("1.0", tk.END)[:-1]`

Comment: Change `textbox.get("1.0", tk.END)` to `textbox.get("1.0", "end-1c")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using:

```
textbox.get("1.0", tk.END+"-1c")
```

Thanks to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824163/how-to-get-the-input-from-the-tkinter-text-widget) and the answer of @xxmbabanexx