# Writing to a CSV file using tkinter

Tags: python, csv, tkinter

i want to save some information in a csv file.
The file is supposed to contain a message from a user, the date and time and his or her name, all in one line.
How would i go about making a GUI with Tkinter so a user can input that information and save it to a CSV file

Any help would be appreciated.

I tried looking for different solutions online but neither of which really helped me.

Comment: Your first step is to create a GUI that takes input from the user. Start there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824163/how-to-get-the-input-from-the-tkinter-text-widget

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

To start off with tkinter you need to create a window by doing

```
window = tkinter.Tk()
```

Then you need to create some text boxes to input the info with text above to say what they are

```
Message_Text = tkinter.Label(window, text="Input a message", font=("Calibri", 50), bg="#a9a9a9", fg="#ffffff")
Message = tkinter.Entry(window, font=("Calibri", 50), bg="#a9a9a9", fg="ffffff")
Date_Label = tkinter.Label(window, text="Input the date and time", font=("Calibri", 50), bg="#a9a9a9", fg="#ffffff")
Date = tkinter.Entry(window, font=("Calibri", 50), bg="#a9a9a9", fg="ffffff")
Name_label = tkinter.Label(window, text="Input your name", font=("Calibri", 50), bg="#a9a9a9", fg="#ffffff")
Name = tkinter.Entry(window, font=("Calibri", 50), bg="#a9a9a9", fg="ffffff")
```

Then after that you need to create a function to get all of that data when the user presses a button but put this at the start

```
def get_data():
    Message_data = Message.get()
    Date_data = Date.get()
    Name_data = Name.get()
    File = open("file.txt", "w")
    File.write(Message_data + ", " + Date_data + ", " + Name_data)
```

Then create a button which we will link the function to

```
button = tkinter.Button(self.window, text="Submit", font=("Calibri", 50), command=get_data, bg="#a9a9a9", fg="#ffffff")
```

Pack all of the objects

```
Message_Text.pack()
Message.pack()
Date_Label.pack()
Date.pack()
Name_label.pack()
Name.pack()
button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

and that should work

Comment: Hey when i try to run the code i get multiple error codes that say "Unresolved reference tkinter"

Comment: You need to import tkinter first with
```
import tkinter
```

Comment: _tkinter.TclError: unknown color name "ffffff"

This is what i get after running it

Comment: @Danxs It should be `"#ffffff"` for a hex color code.

Comment: Oh I thought I fixed that, thanks for clarifying for me