# Get number from textbox

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a textbox which is displayed in my window. I want to get the number from this textbox (inputted from the user) and use it for calculations

```
n=Text(window,width=6,height=2,bg="white").place(x=20,y=80)

num1=n.get(1.0,END)
```

Comment: Please always check if your question has been asked before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824163/how-to-get-the-input-from-the-tkinter-text-widget

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the input from the Tkinter Text Widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824163/how-to-get-the-input-from-the-tkinter-text-widget)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`num1=n.get("1.0","end")`