# Python multiline input and store into variable to call it letter

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, textbox, tkinter-entry

I want to create a Tkinter based user multiline input and store it into a variable to send in another function,
I have tried using
'

```
body_entry = Entry(window,border=0, textvariable=email_body,width=65, bg= '#BAE1E3',font="inter").place(x=330,y=342)
```

'
but this cause me single line entry and i also cant increase it's height to look good.

Then i have tried this.

```
body_TextBox = Text(window,border=0,width=68,height=5,bg= '#BAE1E3',font="inter").place(x=330,y=342)
```

Height can be adjusted here which is quite good but main issue here is it cant be stored in variable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14824163/how-to-get-the-input-from-the-tkinter-text-widget

Comment: Everything you need to know is in available documentation. And of course the text widget data can be stored in a variable.

Comment: @BryanOakley I think what OP means is that there is no `textvariable` option for a `Text` widget.

Comment: got mine answer just used .pack because get method was not working with .place